# Can I dispatch a GitHub reusable workflow that uses secrets?

Tags: github, github-actions

I created a reusable workflow to run unit tests.

In the main workflow, I call this workflow and pass the secrets as arguments.

I also want to trigger this workflow manually sometimes from the GitHub web UI, so I added `workflow_dispatch`.

However, when I do that, I get the error: `Error: Input required and not supplied: token`.  What do I need to do to get access to the secrets when triggering my workflow manually?

I'm confused because in my main workflow (which is triggered by `workflow_dispatch`), I don't need to do anything special to access the secrets.  So I don't understand why this workflow doesn't automatically get access to the secrets from the repo when triggered by `workflow_dispatch`, too:

```
name: unit-tests

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      PAT_GITHUB:
        required: true
jobs:
  update-checker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Check out this repo and submodules."
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT_GITHUB }}
        timeout-minutes: 3
```

When I call this workflow from another workflow and pass the secrets, it executes as expected.

But when I dispatch this workflow from the web UI (screenshot below), it fails:

[image: screenshot of dispatch]

Is it possible to use `workflow_dispatch` and `workflow_call` in the same workflow?  If so, how do I access the secrets when using `workflow_dispatch`?

Comment: How are you calling this workflow and how are you passing your inputs?

Comment: @Fcmam5 I want to call this workflow in two ways: as a reusable workflow and with `workflow_dispatch` (from the web UI).  I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass your secrets from the caller.

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-unit-tests:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-unit-test-wf.yml@main
    secrets:
      PAT_GITHUB: ${{ secrets. PAT_GITHUB }}
```

Or you can use [`secrets: inherit`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-jobsjob_idsecretsinherit):

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-unit-tests:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-unit-test-wf.yml@main
    secrets: inherit
```

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-jobsjob_idsecretsinherit

Comment: This is correct for `workflow_call`.  But what about for `workflow_dispatch` when used in the same workflow as `workflow_call`?

Comment: `workflow_dispatch` should work as it will pull the secret directly and it won't be passed from a caller

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had renamed the secret by mistake in my reusable workflow.

So in the main workflow, I had a secret called `GITHUB_PAT`, but my reusable workflow called it `PAT_GITHUB`.  Since I passed `GITHUB_PAT` to `PAT_GITHUB` in the calling workflow, that worked, but the dispatch failed.

**So the rule here is that if you want to use secrets in a reusable workflow that can also be dispatched, you can't rename the secrets!**